# Trying to figure out the new rotation angle for rocket

Tags: math, cocos2d-iphone

i have this code

```
float angle = rocket.rotation;
float vx = sin(angle * M_PI / 180) * xVelocity;
float vy = cos(angle * M_PI / 180) * yVelocity;
CGPoint direction = ccp(vx, vy);
[rocket setPosition:ccpAdd(rocket.position, direction)];

yVelocity -= 0.2;
```

basically it fires a rocket in the direction i set it to face. This works fine the rocket goes up then comes down fine. I now need to make the rockets rotation change with the new direction i am setting so that the rocket is rotated correctly for the way it is flying. How can i work out the new angle i need to rotate the rocket properly? I'm assuming i can use the new direction to create this new angle but im not sure how. Thanks

Comment: I assume there is a loop in your code? Where is it (I don't know cocos)? Are you trying to accomplish a friction free cannonball shot (with gravity)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you mean, but the first part is not accurate

```
float angle = rocket.rotation;
float vx = sin(angle * M_PI / 180) * xVelocity;
float vy = cos(angle * M_PI / 180) * yVelocity;
```

To say how fast the rocket is going and in what direction, you have two options:

1. Tell direction(angle) and speed(how fast it goes in m/second)
2. Tell horizontal velocity (how fast it goes *horizontally* in m/second) and vertical velocity(m/second)

If you have the velocity(horizontal and vertical), you can calculate the speed and direction. And also, if you have the angle and speed, you can calculate the velocity(horizontal and vertical). Your code seems to be calculating the velocity, from direction and **velocity** instead of direction and **speed**.

```
float angle = rocket.rotation;
xVelocity = sin(angle * M_PI / 180) * speed;
yVelocity = cos(angle * M_PI / 180) * speed;

yVelocity -= 0.2f;//apply gravity

//now we need to find the new angle and speed again
//speed is easy, Pythagoras helps
speed = sqrt(xVelocity*xVelocity + yVelocity*yVelocity);
//angle is more difficult, luckily atan2 solves this:
angle = atan2(yVelocity,xVelocity);

//now we can update the rocket
//Sorry, but I don't know COCOS...
```